# SQL: Out of multiple columns, create a single column that contains the non-null value (with reprex)

Tags: sql

Here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
(
    col1 varchar(10),
    col2 varchar(10), 
    col3 varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO temp (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('a', NULL, NULL),
       (NULL, 'b', NULL),
       (NULL, NULL, 'c');
```

What I would like to return is a single column containing a, b, c.

If this can be done without a CASE WHEN statement, that would be preferred as the actual problem has more than 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(col1, col2, col3)
from temp;
```